# Which CM9 ROM for sony ericsson x10i?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I was about to download a CM ROM file for my phone, [here](https://sites.google.com/site/projectfreexperia/download/cyanogen-mod-9)

Now when I use that (first) uploaded link, it showed me a folder, in which there are a bunch of different versions, such as

- anzu
- aoba
- mango
- etc

and many more.

How do I determine which would be the correct version for me?

My Phone is a Sony Ericsson Xperia x10i, if that is of interest.

I hope this was not asked before, I was searching around for a while.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure why the vote(s) to Close. "How do I determine which would be the correct version" is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there's any support for the x10 from CM for the v9 release.

For reference:

- Xperia Arc => **anzu**
- Xperia Neo => **hallon**
- Xperia Pro => **iyokan**
- Xperia Mini Pro => **mango**
- Xperia Ray => **urushi**
- Xperia Mini => **smultron**
- Xperia Arc S => **ayame**
- Xperia Neo V => **haida**
- Xperia Active => **satsuma**
- Live with Walkman => **coconut**
- Xperia Neo L => **phoenix**

## Edit:

CyanogenMod is a ROM that targets a lot of handsets. A souped up/bloated version of the Stock Vanilla AOSP Android (*the ones found on the Nexus series handsets*)

The FreeXperia project was founded by *jerpelea* who (unofficially works for Sony, gets freebies and contributes to porting CM for that handset etc). Also, FreeXperia project is officially merged into the CyanogenMod tree. Not all legacy devices are supported using the CM ROM, **especially for the newer v9 and v10 (ICS and JB respectively.**

If visiting this [Get CM](http://get.cm) you will actually find that CM is not supporting the legacy devices!

Have not tried FreeXperia, but have heard it is not 100% stable, as some things are broken on it (If anyone wants to correct me, feel free to say so in the comments) :)

Comment: thanks for your answer... on this page https://sites.google.com/site/projectfreexperia/home/device-details/x10-i-a---es209ra it says something about `CyanogenMod9` though... do you have any idea what that means? thanks again!

Comment: @Chips_100 see my edit :)

Comment: thanks for your effort, very informative answer! you definitely helped me out here!

Comment: @t0mm13b you really don't like CM huh? It's not a bad thing that the individual maintainers for CM get free devices from the manufacturers. If they didn't the community would probably have a lot smaller range of custom ROMs for these devices.

Comment: @RyanConrad Its not a bad thing to get freebies alright and I agree yes, but now, the CM founder works for samsung, and there is samsung "orientated-ness" for want of better word for it... samsung devices gets the cm updates quicker than other devices... just saying... it is over-bloated the ROM itself, stock vanilla AOSP <3 ... :D (see that heart symbol there :P) LOL!

Comment: @t0mm13b Samsung, right now, just makes some of the best devices, and the highest selling devices. It's smart to target the "top" devices first. But I don't want to get an off-topic discussion going in the comments, i was just curious. :)

Comment: @RyanConrad no worries at all there mate :) <offtopic/>

Comment: i am running CM10 now on my xperia x10i for about a month now, and i am totally happy with it.
the only thing I noticed (and it is stated on the homepage of cm), is that the hotspot function is not working anymore.
but besides that, its a huge improvement to the official android fw of the x10i!

Answer (score 2):

This is not version of CM - it's [CM code name of device](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Devices). Depending on your device you should download needed release.

Comment: Not a CM code name really, it originates from Sony who labels the kernels for each SEMC chipset! :)

Comment: thanks, nice list! that helped me to get to this site...  http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=es209ra&type= though the downloads are both 404s. was my phone 'dropped' by the developers??

Comment: @Chips_100 [read this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1693256).